# is there a free ide for the Adobe AIR 3.4 SDK

Tags: actionscript, flex4, adobe

Is there a way to use the adobe air 3 SDK with out using adobe's paid software?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows I warmly recommend [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/) (fast, lightweight, free, opensource).

There also cross platform solution like [FDT 5 Free](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/) and [IntelliJ Idea Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).